# remove lines from an output file from diff

Tags: shell-script, scripting, diff

I have a script that uses `diff -c` then puts the output on a text file. What I want is to remove the line that does not have the "!" and display the lines with the exclamation mark. Is this possible? Can the `cut` command do the trick?

I wanted to use `diff -c` because it separates the files from directory1 to directory2.

example:

```
*** 1,3 ****
! 3856715355 /home/dir
  4294967277 /home/dir/file1 <---remove this line
! 154272340 /home/dir/file5
--- 1,4 ----
! 1765342654 /home/dir
  4294967277 /home/dir/file1 <--- remove this line
! 803775803 /home/dir/file4
! 2580902204 /home/dir/file99
```

Comment: `awk '/^!/'` <filler>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- with `grep`:

  ```
  diff -c file1 file2 | grep '^[-!*]'`
  ```
- with `sed`:

  ```
  diff -c file1 file2 | sed '/^[-!*]/!d'
  ```

Comment: but then it also removes the separation from dir1 to dir2

Comment: @midnight27 ... but then you need to put more input in your question.

Comment: @midnight27 see the update

Answer (score 1):

With grep:

```
diff -c file1 file2 | grep -v '^  '
```

none of the other lines start with two spaces: not the ones starting with `!`, and not the line indications.